# Virtual Host using Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

We have development team of 10 people working on Linux platform
our application is hosted on Apache server

Now what i want if every developer is having own codebase in his directory

he can have his own httpd conf file which uses his code base and his port on that server

and whenever he changes the code base he needs run only his apache process

and there is no need to start , restart the  apache server as other people should not get disturbed

so can we do this 
listening same server on different ports with different DocumentRoot and no need to start or restart the whole apache server only individual process of apache need to be started if any changes are done in the local conf file of that user

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to set up separate installed instances of Apache for each developer, or set up individual VMs for each dev.

If going for separate Apache instances, it may be helpful to install them to each user's home directory to ease management (from a permissions standpoint.)

Yes, you should set each instance to listen on a different TCP port.  You must have separate conf files for each instance.  And yes, you can modify the conf files and restart each Apache instance without influencing the others.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with reload instead of restart ? :>